# Probability with Calculus

Tags: calculus, probability

A point is chosen randomly in the region bounded by the curve $y = x^2$ and the line $y = 4$. Find the probability that the $y$-coordinate is less than $a$ for any $a$ in[0,4].

I think that I need to use calculus to find the area under the curve. However, since $y$ is bounded from 0 to 4, it seems like the answer should be $\frac{1}{2}$. Please help guide me in the right direction to get started, even if my intuition is correct.

Comment: You need to find the area, $B$, bounded by the graphs of $y=x^2$ and $y=4$, and the area $B_a$ bounded by the graphs of $y=x^2$ and $y=a$. The probability is then $B_a/B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the area is bound above by $y=4$, the limits of integration go from $[-2,2]$.

The area of interest is

$$A_{total} = 16 - \int_{-2}^{2}x^2dx = \frac{32}{3}.$$

If one considers points no higher than $a$, then the limits of integration on this area go from $[-\sqrt{a},\sqrt{a}]$.  The area of interest here is:

$$A_{\leq a} = 2 \sqrt{a^3} - \int_{-\sqrt{a}}^{\sqrt{a}}x^2dx = \frac{4 \sqrt{a^3}}{3}.$$

Then

$$\frac{A_{\leq a}}{A_{total}} = \frac{\sqrt{a^3}}{8}.$$

Comment: Edited; area of rectangle at top is twice the size I had originally.

Comment: I think the bounds in the first integral should be $[0,2]$ and $[0, \sqrt{a}]$ in the second one

Comment: The parabola $y=x^2$ goes on both sides of the $y$ axis, so the area of interest looks a bit like a shield.  But changing the limits of integration to what you suggest doesn't change the answer; it cuts both integrals in half.

Comment: You are right: sampling also occurs in the left 'side' of the 'shield', so by symmetry it's multiplied by 2.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $x=\sqrt{y}$, so you need the area under the curve: 2$\int_{0}^{a} \sqrt{y} \,dy$.

Answer (score 1):

No integration is needed since Archimedes showed long time ago that the parabola $y=x^2$ divides the rectangle with opposite points $(0,0)$ and $(c,c^2)$ by $1:2$.  Hence the probability is $\dfrac{\frac{2}{3}a\sqrt{a}}{\frac{2}{3}\cdot2^2\cdot2}$.